# Reactjs router onEnter hook authentication cause infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router, infinite-loop

I'm trying to redirect logged in user on dashboard page.

Here is my code:

```
function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
  if(isLoggedIn()) {
    console.log("user is logged in");
    replace('/dashboard');
  } else {
    replace('/');
  } 
}

const Root = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
          <Route onEnter={requireAuth}>
            <Route path="dashboard" component={AllEvents}/>
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}
```

When the user is logged in, my application is running into a loop with a `requireAuth` method.

Here is the screenshot of the console.
[image]

I've already considered two similar questions on StackOverflow which are:

[react Maximum call stack size exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38099497/react-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded)

[React-router, onEnter cause infinite loop with authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45918486/react-router-onenter-cause-infinite-loop-with-authentication)

I've tried both of them, but unfortunately, those examples didn't help me. (I'm also a beginner in React)

Please, tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Which version of react-router you use?

Comment: @MotiKorets I'm quite confused about my version, because in packaje.json I have "react-router": "^3.2.1"  , but after execution of  "npm react-router --v" I got 5.8.0

Comment: run `npm show react-router version` to see package version. what you run shows you `npm` version. Anyway i guess it is react-router 3

Comment: @MotiKorets `npm show react-router version` shows 4.2.0

Comment: Have you tried `<Route path='dashboard' onEnter={requireAuth}>` instead of nesting the dashboard route like you did?

Comment: @brandNew Yes.  `<Route path='dashboard' onEnter={requireAuth}>` was my first construction.

Comment: As far as in know 'onEnter' is removed in v4 and you should use lifecycle method (e.g. `componentDidMount`) instead since in `v4` the routes are just regular components.

Comment: @MotiKorets I will try the varian you propose.

Only one thing is bothering me, that 'onEnter' is actually works, because code from `requireAuth` function is executing. Would it work if I had v4 of react-router?

Comment: The conversation is getting pretty long i would be happy to help but i'm afraid my knowledge here is limited. If you do use v4 take a look at this [example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) which uses `render` props this would be the recommended way to implement authorization. For more discussion about replacement of `onEnter` see [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3854). Again please make sure of the version you use since they are very different.

Comment: @MotiKorets Thank you a lot for your time and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an infinite loop because if the user is logged it always redirect him to `/dashboard` and repeat the redirecting process starting from `/` and again hitting `requireAuth`.

Try:

```
function onlyUnAuthenticated(nextState, replace, callback) {
  if(isLoggedIn()) {
    replace('/dashboard');
  }
  callback();
}

function onlyAuthenticated(nextState, replace, callback) {
  if(!isLoggedIn()) {
    replace('/');
  } 
  callback();
}

const Root = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App} onEnter={onlyUnAuthenticated}>
          <Route path="dashboard" component={AllEvents} onEnter={onlyAuthenticated}/>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I think that you will have to [use callback in the hook](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback).